# How does one describe the symmetric group on an infinite set?

Tags: group-theory

As titled. I'm kind of puzzled by this. Do we have a notion of a symmetric group on an infinite set? If not, how can we extend the symmetric group on finite sets to obtain one? Somewhere online says this symmetric group is complete -- what does that mean?

Comment: There's no difficulty here - the symmetric group on an arbitrary set $X$, infinite or not, is the set of all bijections from $X$ to itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is an arbitrary set, it makes sense to consider the set $S_X$ of bijections $f: X \to X$. This is a group under composition of functions, as you can easily check, and if $X$ is finite, then $S_X = \text{Sym}(X)$ is the group you've already learned about.